# What does sum(1 for c in sentence if c.isupper())) mean in non programming terms

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, command

I need to count the amount of upper-case letters in a user entered sentence.

When I search Google for a solution, I came across the command `sum(1 for c in sentence if c.isupper()))`.

I used it and it works but I also need to explain the code to my teacher.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Be specific about what you don't understand.  As it stands your question is too broad.

Comment: You could also use `sum(c.isupper() for c in sentence)`.  This works because `True` has a numeric value of 1 and `False` has a numeric value of 0.  So you convert the characters into ones and zeroes based on whether or not they are capital, then sum that sequence.

Comment: So you have an assignment, for which you did not write the code yourself, and you are asking for help convincing your teacher you *did* write it yourself?

Answer (score 5):

So for each "c in sentence" (i.e., step through each letter in sentence, making each equal to c for the duration of the loop), substitute in a 1, ("1 for c in sentence"), but only if "c" (the current character) is an uppercase character ("if c.isupper()").

Then, sum (add together) the total number of 1's that were produced (one for each upper case character in the sentence), resulting in the total count of upper case characters.

Comment: Nice. I would also add that `sum()` in the OPs case is a generator expression.

Answer (score 3):

Try rewriting in this way, instead of using list inclusions:

```
count =0
for c in sentence:
    if c.isupper():
        count+=1
print(count)
```

That way, there won't be much to explain!

Comment: Can't go wrong with a simple loop. Also note that it seems that the OP is using Python 3, and `print` needs parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically a loop that is placed inside the sum function. The loop checks every letter in turn and adds a 1 to the total if it finds a capital letter. I.e if the isupper() function returns True.

```
sentence = "Hi My Name is"
a = 0

for c in sentence:
     if c.isupper():
         a = a + 1
     else:
         pass

 print(a, " capital letters")

 b = sum(1 for c in sentence if c.isupper())

 print(b, " capital letters")
```

~

Answer (score 0):

Try to decomposite "sum(1 for c in sentence if c.isupper())":

1) 1 for c in sentence if c.isupper()

It means: "generate 1 if symbol if c is uppercase".

Also, note that (1 for c in sentence if c.isupper()) is a [generator](https://speakerdeck.com/dabeaz/generator-tricks-for-systems-programmers-version-3-dot-0)
But because it placed as a function positional argument it can be placed there without parentheses.

2) sum(...) -- summarize all "1" generated from step 1)

sum expect iterable as an argument: list, tuple, generator or another object that support [iterator protocol](https://treyhunner.com/2016/12/python-iterator-protocol-how-for-loops-work/)

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(1 for i in iterable )
```

will add 1 for each member of iterable. look at this :

```
sum(1 for i in [True,True,True])
```

will return 3

```
sum(10 for i in [True,True,True])
```

will return 30

so for each iteration sum will add the number to itself. 
the "for c in sentence if c.isupper()" return a list of "True"s so for any character that is uppercase sum will add 1.